# RestSharp: Stackoverflow exception at Client.Execute

Tags: json, stack-overflow, restsharp

Hoping you'd be able to assist me with this error - I am getting
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll**
at the time when Client.Execute is called, I've shared my code below:

Thanks in Advance!

---

```
   var Client = new RestClient();
        Client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://dummyurl.com/");
        Client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");

        var eventlist = new List<string>();


        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("event", "application/json");

        string jsonBody = @"{'xxxxx':'xxxx',
                           'xxxx':'Xxxxx'}";

        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonBody);
        request.AddBody(jsonObject);




        IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(request); //<<<--Throws Stackoverflow exception
        var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It blows up on serialising the `JObject` instance. You don't need to overload your code with repeated serialization and JSON parsing.

To pass a ready-made JSON as the request body, just use `AddParamerter(contentType, jsonString, ParameterType.RequestBody);`

Set the content type accordingly to `application/json` or whatever your server wants.